# Gmail account created in incognito mode

Tags: windows

If a gmail account is created in incognito mode in chrome, will that be accessed in normal chrome window? When tried it says account can not be found.

Comment: Did you try restarting the browser or using a different browser?

Answer (score 0):

> If a Gmail account is created in incognito mode in chrome, will that be accessed in normal chrome window?

Really the only major difference, between an Incognito and a Normal Chrome session is the fact, an Incognito session does not keep your cookies.

There are some other differences but those difference have nothing to do with your question.

> When tried it says account can not be found.

You need to use the correct username and password to access the account.  If you are being told the account does not exist, it either was never actually created, or you are using the incorrect username and password.

Comment: Questions specifically about your Google account should be submitted at Web Applications Stack Exchange.  *I am only answering the very limited scope of your question with regards to a Chrome Incognito session.*